# Function to append items in parent/child relation

Tags: swift

I am struggling to implement a function to append array of documents `[Document]` to a specific parent `Document`

here is my implementation, any help?

```
let documents = [Document]()

enum Document {
    case file(File)
    case folder(Folder)
}

class Folder {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let parentId: Int?
    let children: [Document]?
}

class File {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let parentId: Int?
}

func append(_ children: [Document], to parent: Folder) {
    // ??
}
```

Comment: Do you mean append an array of documents to a print **Folder** ?

Comment: @flanker Basically, I am trying to load children data when user press a folder. I want to append loaded data to the pressed folder.

Comment: the comment would have made more sense if it hadn't corrected *parent* to *print*!

Comment: I think the question is ambiguous.  It's not clear whether the idea is to insert the array of documents into an enum-based tree structure (in which case `parentId `properties make little sense) or just to add documents to a Folder (in which case the enum approach makes little sense) and it is a trivial problem.  Either way I'm not sure the data structures are ideal.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do minimal changes but you cannot append unless the inner structures are declared as `var`:

```
class Folder {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    var parentId: Int?
    var children: [Document]?

    init(id: Int, name: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }
}

class File {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    var parentId: Int?

    init(id: Int, name: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }
}

func append(_ children: [Document], to parent: Folder) {
    var newChildren = parent.children ?? []
    newChildren.append(contentsOf: children)

    parent.children = newChildren

    for child in children {
        switch child {
        case .file(let file):
            file.parentId = parent.id
        case .folder(let folder):
            folder.parentId = parent.id
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, the `append` function should be declared inside `Folder`, you should make sure that documents are first removed from their previous folder, you should check whether they are not in the given folder yet, and so on.

Comment: thanks for your replay. I define folders as following case folder(Folder) so updating the children of associated type doesn't update the content of the holder array

Comment: @DotFreelancer I don't know what you are talking about, `Folder` is a reference type (a class).